# Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.NotOutputBufferException SSIS error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using kingswaysoft premium conversion for my ssis package. Recently we migrated to new server with visual studio 2022.Everytime I run my package I get this error. Premium Conversion [415]: An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.NotOutputBufferException: This operation can only be performed on output buffers.

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix this issue. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Biswanath, Thank you for choosing KingswaySoft as your integration solution. For this requirement regarding the Premium Conversion component, please reach out to us at www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us with more details and we will be happy to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this issue is the kingswaysoft component itself, install the most recent version fixes the issue.